# Using keydown for all Web browsers

Tags: jquery

Can someone help me, how can i define the `keyCode`,which,`charcode` into variable. below is my code. but seems not working in Firefox. i already try at Google chrome and i.e. and its work fine.

```
    $(function() {
      $('#txtInput').keydown(function(event) {

      var Key = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
            //number
        if (Key >= 48 && Key <= 57)
            return true;
        //numpad
        else if (Key >= 96 && Key <= 105)
            return true;
        //backspace,tab
        else if (Key >= 8 && Key <= 9)
            return true;
        else return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `event.which` is enough to check the `keyCode` and work fine for all browsers.

According to jQuery doc:

> The **event.which** property normalizes **event.keyCode** and
>   **event.charCode**. It is recommended to watch **event.which** for
>   keyboard key `input`.

***More***

> **event.which** also normalizes button presses (mousedown and
>   mouseupevents), reporting *1 for left button*, *2 for middle*,
>   and *3 for right*. Use **event.which** instead of **event.button**.

***CODE***

```
$('#txtInput').keydown(function(event) {

    var Key = event.which;
    //number
    if (Key >= 48 && Key <= 57) {
        alert('number');
        return true;
    }
    //numpad
    else if (Key >= 96 && Key <= 105) {
        alert('numpad');
        return true;
    }
    //backspace,tab
    else if (Key >= 8 && Key <= 9) {
        alert('backspace, tab');
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/gqcn5/2/)**

#### Read more about [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

Comment: hi thecodeparadox,

At the beginning, im using only event.which. but it didn't work. im using firefox 9.0..

Comment: Owh Tq. i think my another code have problem. Can u help me to check my code. im still new with jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/pYHDE/132/

Comment: @hemiz what you're trying to do? can you explain

Comment: actually, what im trying to do, the textinput will automatically change to decimel while typing. exp: 0.01... and also want to prevent user from enter other than number and numpad.

Comment: @hemiz that means when use start typing like 123.. it will convert to 1.234... right?

Comment: The idea should be like this.

default value 0.00
enter 1 ----> 0.01
enter 0 ----> 0.10
enter 0 ----> 1.00

Comment: @hemiz mate, you should through another question with this, because your current question has no relation with it, as my answer solve your this issue so you should select it as answer